# Hi im getting below error when im trying to run selenium through eclipse for my local URL test

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Getting below error when tried to execute selenium firefox driver for my local URL:

```
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
ession ID: 107f76f0-251f-4d62-9308-2968ed6e354f
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at Gmail_login.main(Gmail_login.java:14)
```

Code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
public class Gmail_login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // objects and variables instantiation
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            String appUrl = "https://localhost/qwer";
    // launch the firefox browser and open the application url
            driver.get(appUrl);
    //maximize the browser window
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //declare and initialize the variable to store the expected title of the webpage.
            String expectedTitle = "Web Login Service";
    //fetch the title of the web page and save it into a string variable
            String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    //compare the expected title of the page with the actual title of the page and print the result
            if (expectedTitle.equals(actualTitle))
            {
              System.out.println("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
            else
            {
             System.out.println("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
    // enter a valid username in the email textbox
            WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
            username.clear();
            username.sendKeys("karthiktest@gmail.com");
                // enter a valid password in the password textbox
            WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
            password.clear();
            password.sendKeys("Welcome");
                // click on the Sign in button
            WebElement SignInButton = driver.findElement(By.name("_eventId_proceed"));
            SignInButton.click();
                // close the web browser
            driver.close();
            System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");
                    // terminate the program
            System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: Pls let me know y im getting above error.It will be really helpful for beginner like me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox driver throws this error if url is not accessible, for example domain name can't be resolved or server blocks connection. It will work if you install webserver on your localhost and serve some content for this url.
You can try to switch firefox to chrome which doesn't throw exception for this scenario. You can also write try-catch block around your `driver.get()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is an INFO message and just so people can see what is going on. 
Its not an error and something to worry about.

this message occurs when using version above selenium3.0.0 and geckodriver

this will not stop the script execution.